# Declaration of this haskell method

Tags: function, haskell, declaration

Im trying to understand Haskell and I have a question: What is the type of this function and how do you call it.

```
two f(a,b) = f a b
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. is `(a,b)` a tuple? Is the question about how to define the function or what the types of the function are?

Comment: How to call it? I'd say `uncurry`!

Comment: yes I think it's a tupple, im talking about two:: ....

Comment: I found it!

curry :: ((a,b)->c) -> a->b->c
curry f a b = f (a,b)
 
uncurry :: (a->b->c) -> ((a,b)->c)
uncurry f (a,b)= f a b

Comment: @user3157778: You can use ghci's `:t` command to find the inferred type of your functions and given a type you can search for similar functions in the stdlib using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a-%3Eb-%3Ec%29+-%3E+%28a%2Cb%29+-%3E+c) or Hayoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take, for example, arguments of type `Int`, then the type of `two` is like this:

```
two :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Int
two f (a,b) = f a b
```

example:

```
two (*) (3,4)
12
```

Explanation:

You are taking a function that takes 2 arguments `(Int -> Int -> Int)`and a tuple `(Int, Int)` and applying that function to `a` and `b`.

The actual type, when not constrained, is actually like this:

```
:t two
two :: (t1 -> t2 -> t) -> (t1, t2) -> t
```

So for example other things are possible:

```
two (++) ("he","llo")
"hello"
```

(etc etc.)

Comment: The type of `two` is quite clearly not constrained to `Int`, it is confusing to suggest it is. Would it not be better to introduce it with its actual type, and then if necessary, provide a concrete example using `Int`?

Comment: true, the type is not constrained. The example with `Int` I felt was more understandable. I'll note it more clearly